# How to find the correct API of a website?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm sort of new to python and I'm having trouble on requesting data from an API.
The API endpoint is:
https://www.poder360.com.br/banco-de-dados/

No matter what I do, I only get the status_code 403.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://pesquisas.poder360.com.br/api/")

print(response.status_code)

response.json()

response.text
```

Comment: You go to the website, and in the Help section you find the description of the API as provided by the website owners. You then code your API consumer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 403 because there is Cloudflare protection. To get past it, you need to include headers/cookies to show Cloudflare that you are not a bot.

Here's a working solution using `urllib`:

```
import urllib.request

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.poder360.com.br',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'dnt': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'ja,ja-JP;q=0.9,en-SG;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
    'cookies': 'PHPSESSID=t2qgtmr3fjv5lg7t2j9hv1gv3e;',
}

request = urllib.request.Request('https://www.poder360.com.br/banco-de-dados/', headers=headers)
r = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
print(r.decode('utf-8'))
```

I've left my PHPSESSID cookie in there as I don't plan to use the site.

Alternatively, if you're using python2, this would work with `python-requests`:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from collections import OrderedDict

headers = OrderedDict([
    ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br'),
    ('Host', 'www.poder360.com.br'),
    ('Authority', 'www.poder360.com.br'),
    ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
    ('Sec-Ch-Ua','"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"'),
    ('Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile', '?0'),
    ('Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform', '"Windows"'),
    ('Dnt', '1'),
    ('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '1'),
    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'),
    ('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Site', 'none'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Mode', 'navigate'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-User', '?1'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Dest', 'document'),
    ('Accept-Language', 'ja,ja-JP;q=0.9,en-SG;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6'),
    ('Cookies', 'PHPSESSID=t2qgtmr3fjv5lg7t2j9hv1gv3e;'),
    
])

s = Session()
s.headers = headers
response = s.get('https://www.poder360.com.br/banco-de-dados/', headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```